# write a function that, given a list, will drop every other element, starting by dropping the first element

Tags: erlang

Im working on some erlang functions and im also not allowed to use library functions.  I have to define a function that drops every other element from a list, starting with the first element.

I have worked on something similar before but i could use BIFs and now i am struggling.

For example, `alternate([1,2,3,four,5,6])` is `[2,four,6]`. I am not sure how to implement it.

```erlang
spec drop_word(string()) -> string().

drop_word([]) -> [];
drop_word([O|Op]) -> case wsp(O)  of 
true -> Op;
false -> drop_word(Op)
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alternate(List) ->
    alternate(List, _Index=0).

alternate([_|T], Index) when Index rem 2 == 0 ->  %even indexes
    alternate(T, Index+1);
alternate([H|T], Index) when Index rem 2 == 1 ->  %odd indexes
    [H | alternate(T, Index+1)];
alternate([], _Index) ->
    [].
```

In the shell:

```
12> a:alternate([1,2,3,four,5,6]).
[2,four,6]

13> a:alternate([1,2,3,four,5]).
[2,four]
```

But, that can be simplified to:

```
alternate(List) ->
    evens(List).

evens([_|T]) ->
    odds(T);
evens([]) -> [].

odds([H|T]) ->
    [H | evens(T)];
odds([]) -> [].
```

In the shell:

```
6> a:alternate([1,2,3,four,5,6]).
[2,four,6]

7> a:alternate([1,2,3,four,5]).  
[2,four]
```

Here's an accumulator version:

```
alternate(List) ->
    evens(List, []).

evens([_|T], Acc) ->
    odds(T, Acc);
evens([], Acc) -> 
    lists:reverse(Acc).

odds([H|T], Acc) ->
    evens(T, [H|Acc]);
odds([], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

In the shell:

```
20> a:alternate([1,2,3,four,5,6]).
[2,four,6]

21> a:alternate([1,2,3,four,5]).  
[2,four]
```

Note that `lists:reverse()` is highly optimized, so you would never do `List ++ [X]` many times, which traverses the whole list every time you add an element to the end of the list.  Rather, you should always choose to add an element to the head of a list, then call `lists:reverse()`.  Oh yeah, no library functions...a `reverse()` function is easy to implement yourself, and although it won't be optimized like the erlang version, it will still be more efficient than doing `List ++ [X]` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to drop any elements with position which is even. So you can do it like below:

```
-module(test).
-compile([export_all,debug_info]).

alternate(L) -> do_alternate(L, 0, length(L)).
do_alternate(_, L, L) -> [];
do_alternate([H|T], N, L) ->
    case (N band 1) == 0 of
      true -> do_alternate(T, N+1, L);
      false -> [H] ++ do_alternate(T, N+1, L)
    end.
```

Result in shell:

```
1> c(test).                         
test.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,test}
2> test:alternate([1,2,3,four,5,6]).
[2,four,6]
```

Moreover, if your `List` only has integer numbers, so you can use BIF like below:

```
3> lists:partition(fun(A) -> A rem 2 == 1 end, [1,2,3,4,5,6]). 
{[1,3,5],[2,4,6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two atoms `drop` and `keep` two match the alternating clauses of `do_alternate`. Details below in comments.

```erlang
-module(so).
-export([alternate/1]).

% The exported function starts the actual function and tells it to match the `drop`
% clause. Kept elements of L will be collected in the third argument.
alternate(L) -> do_alternate(drop, L, []).


% The `drop` clause will call the `keep` clause and pass the tail T and the
% currently collected list Acc. The head H will be dropped.
do_alternate(drop, [_|T], Acc) -> do_alternate(keep, T, Acc);

% The `keep` clause will call the `drop` claues and pass the tail T and the
% currently collected list Acc with the head H prepented to it.
do_alternate(keep, [H|T], Acc) -> do_alternate(drop, T, Acc ++ [H]);

% If the arugment list is empty, return the accumulated list.
do_alternate(_, [], Acc) -> Acc.
```

Example usage:

```
> c(so).
{ok,so}
9> so:alternate([1,2,3,4,5,6]).
[2,4,6]
10> so:alternate([1,2,3,4,5,6,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven]).
[2,4,6,eight,ten]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pattern match on the list, taking two elements at a time:

```
alternate([_Odd, Even | T]) ->
    [Even] ++ alternate(T);
alternate([]) ->
    [].
```

The specification doesn't say what happens if the list has an odd number of elements, so this function will just crash with a "function clause" error in that case.  You could add a third clause to handle that - presumably dropping the last element would be a sensible thing to do:

```
alternate([_Last]) ->
    [];
```